# Current passed through a charged conductor

Tags: electric-current, charge, conductors

If I take a charged conductor and pass a current through it and stop. Will the charge remain on that conductor or would it be flown away by the current?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass a current through the conductor, you connect a source of electrons and a place deficit of electrons, and electrons flow from one to the other.

When you do that, the charge on the conductor will spread throughout the circuit. It will leak some.

If the circuit is grounded, then the charge will all escape.

If there is a switch that can prevent or stop the current from flowing, and if the ground is on the conductor side of the switch, then the charge will all escape whether the current ever flows or not.

Comment: Well, can we say that after a long time (infinity to be precise), the total charge will escape?

Comment: Over infinite time when things change, It's predictable that the total charge will escape, and will eventually be replaced by other total charges which on average will be reversed about half the time which will also escape, until eventually the conductor changes so much we no longer would consider it the same conductor.

I hope that doesn't come across as snide. You might have intended to talk about infinite time when only one or a few things are allowed to vary.